# Copy files to a network path using python script

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to copy files from hard disk to a network path drive using python script. MY script is simple however it doesnt work since it seems that I need to add credentials in order to perftorm such action.

```
import glob, os
import shutil

myPath = "E://data//"
dst  = "C://Users//user//networkPath//"
for file in os.listdir(myPath):

 shutil.copy2(myPath+file, dst+file)
```

This works only for default system directories and not for a network path. What should I do in case of network path?

**EDIT** I am trying to do something like this:

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(0, None, '\\\\'+"http://ip:port/", "user", "pass") however I am getting the message:
```

> pywintypes.error: (67, 'WNetAddConnection2', 'The network path was not found.')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import win32wnet

win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(0, None, '\\\\'+host, None, username, password)
shutil.copy(source_file, '\\\\'+host+dest_share_path+'\\')'
win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2('\\\\'+host, 0, 0)
```

Edit : Code Formatted

Comment: I had issues with win32wnet command WNetAddConnection2 I am receiving a pywintypes.error: (67, 'WNetAddConnection2', 'The network name cannot be found.')